# How to use angulars templates when loading other pages with onsenui

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a search page for user input:

```
<ons-navigator title="WELCOME" >
    <ons-page class="center">
        <h1>PICK SOMETHING</h1>
        <ons-search-input ng-model="searchText"
                          placeholder="Search">
        </ons-search-input>
        <br />
        <ons-button type="large" ng-click="FindResult($scope);">
            Find how I get there
        </ons-button>


    </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
```

and page2.html has:

```
<ons-page class="center">
<h1>{{searchText}}</h1>
```

The {{searchText}} remains empty as if its not looking at the same controller.

How should I be approaching cross-page data binding?

Answer (score 0):

Have you assigned a controller to page2.html with an ng-controller tag in the html or by using a config in the js file?

You can read up on Angular controllers in the documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a controller and you need to bind the input to object rather than primitive variable.

so instead of

```
ng-model="searchText"
```

use

```
ng-model="search.text"
```

Make sure a global controller is the owner of the model.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['onsen.directives']);

app.controller('AppController', function($scope){
  $scope.search = {
    text: ""
  };
  $scope.FindResult = function(){
    $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('page2.html', {title: 'Page 2'});
  }
});
```

Here I set the controller to body tag so that first page and page2.html can see the controller.

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">
  <ons-navigator title="WELCOME" >
    <ons-page class="center">
      <h1>PICK SOMETHING</h1>
      <ons-search-input ng-model="search.text"
                        placeholder="Search">
      </ons-search-input>
      <br />
      <ons-button type="large" ng-click="FindResult();">
          Find how I get there
      </ons-button>


  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
```

Here is the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/RVqjRh?p=preview